# GetHtml vs PrintHtml in PHP?

Tags: php, memory-management, printing, get

Do you think I should use this method:

```
function PrintHtml() {
  echo "Hello World!";
}

Printhtml();
```

Instead of this:

```
function GetHtml() {
  $html = "Hello ";
  $html .= "World!";

  return $html;
}

echo GetHtml();
```

In order to reduce memory usage? I plan on doing the whole system with Print / Get functions so which route would you go?

Answer (score 1):

This should not be and is not about memory footprint / performance.

`Echo`ing stuff inside a function is pretty crappy behaviour because you are forcing yourself and other people using the system to directly using the function instead of being able to run the function and do something with the data it returns.

In the first case this would mean having to buffer and there is even more trouble with `echo`ing from inside a function instead of properly returning data in the long run (i.e. testing etc). Go for the second option. However  I really don't know exactly what you are cooking in the function, because often you don't want to "build" HTML inside some function. That is what templates are for.

Also note that it is a common convention that functions do not start with an Uppercase letter.

Comment: I tend to agree. Could you give me an example of how these templates work?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffman already said, I think it's better to use the second method. With the second method you have also the option to prepare it, for example replacing some tags or what ever you want. You have more control over the output.

Comment: Yeah I suppose you are right. I'm thinking of creating a "structure" class file that has GetHeader(), GetFooter(), GetBox($type) etc. does this count as a "template"?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class which loads your templatefile. In my example I created a file called index.php, which is stored in the folder "templates" > "myTemplate". You could use following class.

```
<?php
    // defines
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    define('_root', dirname(__FILE__));

    // template class
    class template
    {
        var templateName;
        var templateDir;

        function __construct($template)
        {
            $this->templateName = $template;
            $this->templateDir = _root.DS.'templates'.DS.$this->templateName;
        }

        function loadTemplate()
        {
            // load template if it exists
            if(is_dir($this->templateDir) && file_exists())
            {
                // we save the output in the buffer, so that we can handle the output
                ob_start();

                include_once($file);

                // save output
                $output = ob_get_contents();

                // clear buffer
                ob_end_clean();

                // return output
                return $output;
            }
            else
            {
                // the output when the template does not exists or the index.php is missing
                return 'The template "'.$this->templateName.'" does not exists or the "index.php" is missing.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

It's only a basic class, which only loads the template. Now you can call this class like this:

```
<?php
    // example for using the class
    include_once('class.template.php');
    $template = new template('myTemplate');
    $html = $template->loadTemplate();

    echo $html;
?>
```

In the index.php you can now write your html stuff like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<head>
    <title>My Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        My Content
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helped you a little bit.